# Inventory Transfer Issue Between Inventories

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

"I have two inventories, and inventory scripts are defined separately for each of them. What I want to do is transfer an item from one inventory to the other, but I'm getting an output that seems like I'm operating within the same inventory, as seen in the GIF below.

[image]

**InventorySlot** script is a script that exists in each inventory slot. It operates by detecting mouse clicks and performing actions accordingly.

```
public class InventorySlot : MonoBehaviour, IDragHandler, IPointerUpHandler, IPointerDownHandler
{
    public ItemObject item;
    public GameObject groundItemPrefab;

    public Canvas canvas;
    private CanvasGroup cg;


    public GameObject itemSlot;
    public RectTransform selectedRectTransform;
    public Image slotItemImage;
    public TextMeshProUGUI slotItemAmount;
    public Vector3 slotStartPosition;

    [Header("InventoryOut")]
    public Inventory inventory;
    private GameObject tempItemGameObject;
    private GameObject player;

    ItemObject tempItem;
    public int slotIndex;
    public InventoryDisplay inventoryDisplay;

    [Header("ChangeInventorySlots")]
    public int selectedslotIndex;
    public int changedSlotIndex;

    private void Start()
    {
        cg = GetComponent<CanvasGroup>();
        if (item != null)
        {
            slotItemImage.sprite = item.itemSprite;
        }
        player = GameObject.Find("Player");
        slotStartPosition = selectedRectTransform.position;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (item != null)
        {
            slotItemImage.sprite = item.itemSprite;
            slotItemAmount.SetText(item.amount.ToString());
        }  
    }

    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        if (selectedRectTransform != null)
        {
            Vector3 mousePosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            mousePosition.z = 0f;
            selectedRectTransform.anchoredPosition += eventData.delta / canvas.scaleFactor;
            selectedRectTransform.parent.SetAsLastSibling();
        }
       
    }

    public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        bool foundSlot = false;

        foreach (GameObject overObj in eventData.hovered)
        {
            if (overObj != null)
            {
                foundSlot = true;
                selectedRectTransform.anchoredPosition = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
                InventorySlot slot = overObj.GetComponent<InventorySlot>();
                Inventory ınventory = overObj.GetComponent<Inventory>();
                if (slot != null)
                {
                    changedSlotIndex = slot.slotIndex;
                    inventory.ChangeItemSlot(selectedslotIndex,changedSlotIndex);
                }
            }
        }
        if (!foundSlot)
        {
            tempItemGameObject = Instantiate(groundItemPrefab);
            tempItemGameObject.GetComponent<GroundItem>().item = tempItem;
            tempItemGameObject.transform.position = player.transform.position + new Vector3(2f,0f,0f);
            selectedRectTransform.anchoredPosition = new Vector3(0,0,0);
            
            inventory.inventory[slotIndex] = null;
            inventoryDisplay.UpdateSlots();

        }
        cg.blocksRaycasts = true;
    }

    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
    {        
        foreach (GameObject overObj in eventData.hovered)
        {
            if (overObj != null)
            {
                InventorySlot slot = overObj.GetComponent<InventorySlot>();            
                if (slot != null && slot.item != null)
                {
                    tempItem = ItemObject.CreateInstance<ItemObject>();
                    tempItem.itemName = slot.item.itemName;
                    tempItem.itemSprite = slot.item.itemSprite;
                    tempItem.amount = slot.item.amount;
                    tempItem.stackable = slot.item.stackable;
                    selectedslotIndex = slot.slotIndex;
                }
            }
        }
        cg.blocksRaycasts = false;
    }
}
```

**Inventory** script is a script that exists in each inventory element and handles addition and rearrangement operations.

```
public class Inventory : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Inventory")]
    public List<ItemObject> inventory = new List<ItemObject>();
    public int inventoryIndex;

    public InventoryDisplay inventoryDisplay;

    public void ChangeItemSlot(int selectedSlotIndex, int changedSlotIndex)
    {
        if (selectedSlotIndex >= 0 && selectedSlotIndex < inventory.Count && changedSlotIndex >= 0 && selectedSlotIndex < inventory.Count)
        {
            ItemObject temp = inventory[selectedSlotIndex];
            inventory[selectedSlotIndex] = inventory[changedSlotIndex];
            inventory[changedSlotIndex] = temp;
            inventoryDisplay.UpdateSlots();
        }
    }

    public void AddItem(GameObject item)
    {    
        ItemObject newItem = ItemObject.CreateInstance<ItemObject>();
        newItem.amount = item.GetComponent<GroundItem>().item.amount;
        newItem.itemName = item.GetComponent<GroundItem>().item.itemName;
        newItem.itemSprite = item.GetComponent<GroundItem>().item.itemSprite;
        newItem.stackable = item.GetComponent<GroundItem>().item.stackable;

        bool addedToStack = false;
        bool inventoryFull = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < inventory.Count; i++)
        {
            if (inventory[i] != null && inventory[i].itemName == newItem.itemName && newItem.stackable)
            {
                inventory[i].amount += newItem.amount;
                inventoryDisplay.UpdateSlots();
                Destroy(item.gameObject);
                addedToStack = true;
                inventoryFull = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!addedToStack)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < inventory.Count; i++)
            {
                if (inventory[i] == null)
                {
                    inventory[i] = newItem;
                    inventoryDisplay.UpdateSlots();
                    Destroy(item.gameObject);
                    inventoryFull = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (inventoryFull)
        {
            Debug.Log("Inventory is Full");
        }
    }
}
```

I thought of doing this by getting the index of what I clicked and checking it. If the index of what I clicked is different from the index of where I dropped it, I would remove it from one inventory and add it to the other.

I'm still getting the same index in both inventories. The reason for this is that the scripts are operating independently within their own contexts. However, I can't figure out how to solve this.
**Thank you in advance.**

Comment: Hi, could you provide more information, mainly the collider bounds of both inventory screens? The code looks correct, the only thing that, I think could cause trouble is your `OnPointerUp` method. I would recommend to add extensive debug logging in it, specifically what inventory you are getting, and what are the other elements in your foreach loop that you are looping over.  putting breakpoints inside and stepping through would help a lot.

Comment: In general in the `OnPointerDown` ... you already know that **this** object is the one receiving the `OnPointerDown` event .. you loop is quite redundant and `slot` should be the same as `this`

Comment: .. it sounds a bit like your items never actually leave their parent, you probably will have to re-parent them to the correct inventory they were dropped on

Comment: Can you take a look at the response I added, by the way, thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[Header("DifferentInventories")]
    public int firstInventory;
    public int secondInventory;
    ItemObject newItem;

public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    bool foundSlot = false;

    foreach (GameObject overObj in eventData.hovered)
    {
        if (overObj != null)
        {
            foundSlot = true;
            selectedRectTransform.anchoredPosition = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
            InventorySlot slot = overObj.GetComponent<InventorySlot>();
            
            if (slot != null)
            {
                secondInventory = slot.inventory.inventoryIndex;

                if (firstInventory == secondInventory && slotIndex != slot.slotIndex)
                {
                    newItem = ItemObject.CreateInstance<ItemObject>();
                    newItem.itemName = tempItem.itemName;
                    newItem.itemSprite = tempItem.itemSprite;
                    newItem.amount = tempItem.amount;
                    newItem.stackable = tempItem.stackable;
                    GameObject newObject = new GameObject("MyNewGameObject");
                    GroundItem groundItemScript = newObject.AddComponent<GroundItem>();
                    groundItemScript.item = newItem;                                
                    changedSlotIndex = slot.slotIndex;
                    inventory.ChangeItemSlot(selectedslotIndex, changedSlotIndex);
                    slot.inventory.AddNormalItem(newObject, slot.slotIndex);
                    inventoryDisplay.UpdateSlots();
                    Destroy(newObject);
                }
                else if (firstInventory == secondInventory && slotIndex == slot.slotIndex)
                {
                    newItem = ItemObject.CreateInstance<ItemObject>();
                    newItem.itemName = tempItem.itemName;
                    newItem.itemSprite = tempItem.itemSprite;
                    newItem.amount = tempItem.amount;
                    newItem.stackable = tempItem.stackable;
                    GameObject newObject = new GameObject("MyNewGameObject");
                    GroundItem groundItemScript = newObject.AddComponent<GroundItem>();
                    groundItemScript.item = newItem;
                    slot.inventory.AddNormalItem(newObject, slot.slotIndex);
                    inventoryDisplay.UpdateSlots();
                    Destroy(newObject);
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.Log(firstInventory + " " + secondInventory);
                    newItem = ItemObject.CreateInstance<ItemObject>();
                    newItem.itemName = tempItem.itemName;
                    newItem.itemSprite = tempItem.itemSprite;
                    newItem.amount = tempItem.amount;
                    newItem.stackable = tempItem.stackable;
                    GameObject newObject = new GameObject("MyNewGameObject");
                    GroundItem groundItemScript = newObject.AddComponent<GroundItem>();
                    groundItemScript.item = newItem;
                    slot.inventory.AddNormalItem(newObject, slot.slotIndex);
                    inventoryDisplay.UpdateSlots();
                    Destroy(newObject);
                }

            }
            
           
        }
    }
    if (!foundSlot)
    {
        //Debug.Log("yere bıraktı");
        //burada envanterden attığımda her zaman 2f sağında spawnlanacak bunu karakter nereye dönükse ona göre yapmasını ayarlayacağım.
        tempItemGameObject = Instantiate(groundItemPrefab);
        tempItemGameObject.GetComponent<GroundItem>().item = tempItem;
        tempItemGameObject.transform.position = player.transform.position + new Vector3(2f,0f,0f);
        selectedRectTransform.anchoredPosition = new Vector3(0,0,0);
        
        inventory.inventory[slotIndex] = null;
        inventoryDisplay.UpdateSlots();

    }
    cg.blocksRaycasts = true;
}

public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
{        
    foreach (GameObject overObj in eventData.hovered)
    {
        if (overObj != null)
        {
            InventorySlot slot = overObj.GetComponent<InventorySlot>();
            if (slot != null && slot.item != null)
            {
                tempItem = ItemObject.CreateInstance<ItemObject>();
                tempItem.itemName = slot.item.itemName;
                tempItem.itemSprite = slot.item.itemSprite;
                tempItem.amount = slot.item.amount;
                tempItem.stackable = slot.item.stackable;
                selectedslotIndex = slot.slotIndex;
                firstInventory = slot.inventory.inventoryIndex;
                slot.inventory.RemoveItem(slotIndex);
            }
        }
    }
    cg.blocksRaycasts = false;
}
```

I have defined two variables, and these variables will hold the indices of the inventories, allowing me to determine which inventory I am working with.

In the OnPointerDown function, I retrieve the index of the inventory I'm starting the operation on.

**firstInventory = slot.inventory.inventoryIndex;**

In the OnPointerUp function, I obtain the index of the inventory I've released, and based on that, I make the necessary changes using if-else statements.

**secondInventory = slot.inventory.inventoryIndex;**

Additionally, I've split the AddItem function in the inventory script into two functions. The first one adds items obtained from the ground to the inventory, and the second one adds items from a different inventory to the current one.

```
public void AddGroundItem(GameObject item)
    {    
        ItemObject newItem = ItemObject.CreateInstance<ItemObject>();
        newItem.amount = item.GetComponent<GroundItem>().item.amount;
        newItem.itemName = item.GetComponent<GroundItem>().item.itemName;
        newItem.itemSprite = item.GetComponent<GroundItem>().item.itemSprite;
        newItem.stackable = item.GetComponent<GroundItem>().item.stackable;

        bool addedToStack = false;
        bool inventoryFull = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < inventory.Count; i++)
        {
            if (inventory[i] != null && inventory[i].itemName == newItem.itemName && newItem.stackable)
            {
                inventory[i].amount += newItem.amount;
                inventoryDisplay.UpdateSlots();
                Destroy(item.gameObject);
                addedToStack = true;
                inventoryFull = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!addedToStack)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < inventory.Count; i++)
            {
                if (inventory[i] == null)
                {
                    inventory[i] = newItem;
                    inventoryDisplay.UpdateSlots();
                    Destroy(item.gameObject);
                    inventoryFull = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (inventoryFull)
        {
            Debug.Log("Inventory is Full");
        }
    }

    public void AddNormalItem(GameObject item, int specifiedIndex)
    {
        ItemObject newItem = ItemObject.CreateInstance<ItemObject>();
        newItem.amount = item.GetComponent<GroundItem>().item.amount;
        newItem.itemName = item.GetComponent<GroundItem>().item.itemName;
        newItem.itemSprite = item.GetComponent<GroundItem>().item.itemSprite;
        newItem.stackable = item.GetComponent<GroundItem>().item.stackable;

        bool addedToStack = false;
        bool inventoryFull = true;

        if (specifiedIndex >= 0 && specifiedIndex < inventory.Count && inventory[specifiedIndex] == null)
        {
            inventory[specifiedIndex] = newItem;
            inventoryDisplay.UpdateSlots();
            inventoryFull = false;
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < inventory.Count; i++)
            {
                if (inventory[i] != null && inventory[i].itemName == newItem.itemName && newItem.stackable)
                {
                    inventory[i].amount += newItem.amount;
                    inventoryDisplay.UpdateSlots();
                    addedToStack = true;
                    inventoryFull = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!addedToStack)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < inventory.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (inventory[i] == null)
                    {
                        inventory[i] = newItem;
                        inventoryDisplay.UpdateSlots();
                        inventoryFull = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (inventoryFull)
        {
            Debug.Log("Inventory is Full");
        }
    }
```

I've managed to make some modifications to the inventory and item slot scripts,I still have some questions in my mind. For example:

Will this cause performance issues in the future?
Or what can I improve on?